# Javascript value amount does not change

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem is, that when I press the "deposit" button, the function "depositMoney" should run and add the desired amount to the current balance.
However, it does not do that and the balance stays at $0.

```
// Variable declarations
let balance = document.getElementById("balance");
let balanceAmount = 0;

let depositInput = 0;
depositInput = document.getElementById("depositAmount").value;
let depositButton = document.getElementById("depositButton");


// Cash amount
let cash = document.getElementByIJd("cash")
let cashAmount = 1000;

// Draw on screen
balance.innerHTML = "$" +  balanceAmount;
cash.innerHTML = "$" + cashAmount;

// This function runs through onclick in the html document
function depositMoney() {
    balanceAmount = balanceAmount + depositInput;
    balance.innerHTML = "$" +  balanceAmount;
}
```

```
                <div class="atm-deposit">
                    <input type="text" name="Deposit Amount" id="depositAmount">
                    <input type="button" value="Deposit" id="depositButton" onclick="depositMoney()">
                </div>
```

Comment: Please post the full HTML.

Comment: You should also inspect the console for errors.

Comment: Hi ! Maybe we could talk about the `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByIJd is not a function` ? ;)

Comment: That is because the values of `balanceAmount` and `depositInput` are never updated when the function `depositMoney` is called. JS variables are not "reactive" in the way you expect. If you want to retrieve the updated value of these elements, you will need to retrieve them again and assign to the variables, i.e. `balanceAmount = document.getElementById("balance").value` and `depositInput = document.getElementById("depositAmount").value`